# What is the meaning of syntactical parameter written in javascript documentation

Tags: javascript

As I'm going through the javascript documentation i seet that in syntax section i see that `call([thisObj[, arg1[, arg2[,  [, argN]]]]])`

can any one explain why is this written `[thisObj[` with open squire bracket starting and closed with open squire bracket.

Similarly  `arg1[, arg2[,  [, argN]]]]]`

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean you're seeing this in the documentation, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It represents an *optional* argument.

i.e.

`thisObj` is optional.

`arg1` is optional, but if you provide it then `thisObj` is mandatory.

`arg2` is optional, but if you provide it then `arg1` is mandatory.

…and then the `[, argN]` just means you can keep going for any number of arguments.